# Expected identifier using 'else' in C

Tags: c

Trying to code a simple "guess a number" game in C, it's telling me there is an expected identifier on one of my 'else' and I'm not sure what the issue is, does anyone see it? (`**` are around the `else` where the issue is)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int correctnumber,guessnumber;

    correctnumber = 8;

    printf("Welcome to the guess-a-number game!\n");
    printf("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 15. What is it?");
    scanf("%d", &guessnumber);

    if (guessnumber == correctnumber) printf("That was 8!");

    else
    {if (guessnumber > correctnumber)printf("No, try something lower:");
    else printf("No, try something higher:");
        scanf("%d", &guessnumber);
        if (guessnumber == correctnumber) printf("That was 8!");
        }

    **else**
        {if (guessnumber > correctnumber) printf("No, try something lower:");
    else printf("No, try something higher:");
         if (guessnumber == correctnumber) printf("That was 8!");

    else
                {printf("Sorry, you missed it. The answer was 8");

}
```

Comment: It might be just that `**else**` you have at line 15, replace it with an `else` and try again.

Comment: there is definitely problem with the format of the code but also please explain what are you want trying to do.

Comment: Your coding style is making your code difficult to read. I suggests the use curly [braces with your if-statements](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html). Do what you will with this suggestion. Make of my suggestions what you will.

Answer (score 1):

You have put two `else` statements in a row in your program. Check your logic and the location of your {} brackets. The following is a better-formatted version of your code, which more clearly shows the problem:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int correctnumber, guessnumber;

    correctnumber = 8;

    printf("Welcome to the guess-a-number game!\n");
    printf("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 15. What is it?");
    scanf("%d", &guessnumber);

    if (guessnumber == correctnumber)
        printf("That was 8!");

    else {
        if (guessnumber > correctnumber)
            printf("No, try something lower:");
        else
            printf("No, try something higher:");
        scanf("%d", &guessnumber);
        if (guessnumber == correctnumber)
            printf("That was 8!");
    }

    else
    {
        if (guessnumber > correctnumber)
            printf("No, try something lower:");
        else
            printf("No, try something higher:");
        if (guessnumber == correctnumber)
            printf("That was 8!");

        else {
            printf("Sorry, you missed it. The answer was 8");
        }
```

so your structure is

```
if () {/*block of code*/}
else {/*block of code*/}
else {/*block of code*/}
```

That second `else` causes the error.

Formatting your code properly is a good habit. Xcode can do that for you. It makes reading the program's logic easier.